# How to know when a task completes at the await?

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library

I would like to do something like this:

```
Loading = true;
var data = await DataProvider.DoWorkAsync();
Loading = false; // but have this not get set until the data is loaded
```

Loading is just a property bound to a progress indicator in a WPF app, and DataProvider is injected.  I simply want to know when the data has completed loading so I can update the progress indicator.

Edit:
Updated the `DoWork()` to `DoWorkAsync()` as it is in my code.  The `DoWorkAsync()` and `DoWork()` calls look like this

```
public Task<DataStructure> DoWorkAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run(() => DoWork());
}

public DataStructure DoWork() 
{
    var dataStructure = new DataStructure();
    // Heavy lifting here
    return dataStructure;
}
```

The code above doesn't work, and since I'm not actually returning a task with my await, I'm not sure if `ContinueWith()` is the right approach here.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: That code certainly should work; that's the way to do it. Sounds like `DoWork` may not be coded properly?

Comment: is there any DoWorkCompleted event?

Comment: Conceptually the code after an await is a continuation just like ContinueWith. You should show how `DoWork` is implemented.

Comment: What is the method's signature? Did you use `async void` instead of `async Task` ?

Comment: Thanks all, it sounds like this should work... I will update with the `DoWork()` call as well... if that looks okay, then there must be something else going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: What I see is if I have a list of items where each one is initialized and does that async heavy work, I see odd stuff- like one progress indicator shows progress complete, then the app freezes until all other items complete the work.  Or none of them show work being completed until all the work for all items is done.  I'm going to play with the sample code and see what the simplest reproduction I can get going is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that should work fine.

Try to make a new WPF-app that just contains the following code in the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loading = true;
        var data = await DoWorkAsync();
        txt.Text = data.Name;
        Loading = false;
    }

    public Task<DataStructure> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => DoWork());
    }

    public DataStructure DoWork()
    {
        var dataStructure = new DataStructure();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        dataStructure.Name = "Test";
        return dataStructure;
    }

    public class DataStructure
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    private bool _loading = false;
    public bool Loading
    {
        get { return _loading; }
        set
        {
            _loading = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Loading"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

..and a XAML file with something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="{Binding Loading}" Height="50" Width="100" />
    <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" />
</StackPanel>
```

You should see that the button eventhandler will call the `DoWorkAsync` method asynchronously and start the progressbar. After the `Task` has completed the `TextBlock` will update and the progressbar will stop.

Maybe you can use this example to figure out what you are doing different?